# Как обрезать углы?

Tags: css

Есть вот такие элементы на страницы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите у них добавлено свойство border-radius: 50px 50px 0px 0px;
Но получается, что углы становится закругленными, а как сделать чтоб было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтоб углы были не закругленные, а ровные...

Comment: То есть вы хотите получить равнобедренную трапецию?

Comment: да, в точку))..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать такой вариант.
Но надо отметить тот факт, что не будет работать в `EDGE && IE`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clip-svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #333;
  padding: 0 10%;
  margin: 60px auto;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 10% 0%, 90% 0%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 10% 0%, 90% 0%, 100% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#polygon");
  clip-path: url("#polygon");
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<svg class="clip-svg">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="polygon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
   <polygon points="0 1, 0.1 0, 0.9 0, 1 1" />
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

При этом значения по высоте можно указывать в других единицах, не только в процентах. Но, любой представленный вариант зависит от ваших конкретных целей и задач. SVG добавлен для более лучшей поддержки браузеров, но, IE остается больной темой в этом вопросе.

И еще один более простой вариант:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 0;
  width: 120px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 60px solid #333;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 60px auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Текст вкладки</div>
```

Данный пример с хорошей поддержкой браузеров, но, менее "гибкий". Повторюсь, все зависит от конкретных задач.

Answer (score 2):

Через border-radius не вижу решения, но если мы знаем высоту элемента, то через псевдоэлементы получится так:

```css
.rect {
color: #fff;
width: 300px;
height: 20vh; /* высота элемента */
background-color: #000000;
position: relative;
margin-left: 40px;
}
.rect:after, .rect:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border: 10vh solid #000000; /* половина высоты элемента */
}
.rect:after{
left: 100%;
border-right-color: transparent;
border-left-width: 20px;  /* длина наклонных */
border-right-width: 20px; /*    элементов    */
border-top-color: transparent;
}
.rect:before{
right: 100%;
border-left-color: transparent;
border-right-width: 20px;  /* длина наклонных */
border-left-width: 20px;   /*    элементов    */
border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще вариант

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.trapeze {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
  background-color: orange;
  transform-origin: 50% bottom;
  transform: rotateX(50deg);
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  line-height: 5;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="trapeze"></div>
  <p class="text">text</p>
</div>
```